# How to write constructor function for DOM element in javascript/coffeescript

Tags: javascript, dom, coffeescript

I am aware of `document.createElement` and `document.registerElement` but these method don't allow to write constructor with custom arguments I want something like what **new Image()** do for img tag. I wrote following code :

```
SVG = document.getElementById('sprite').content.children[0]
class DisplayObject
    constructor: (childs)->
        clone = document.importNode SVG
        clone.__proto__ = {
            constructor: DisplayObject
            __proto__: SVG.__proto__
        }
        clone.constructor = DisplayObject
        return clone
    __proto__: SVG.__proto__
    test: ->
        console.log 'test method'
```

The problem is I can't access test method from returned clone object. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
SVG = document.getElementById('flybar').children[0]

class DisplayObject
    constructor: (children)->
      @__proto__ = SVG.__proto__
      return
    test: =>
        console.log 'test method'
```

Comment: it didn't work. the problem is when you want to call `document.body.appendChild( new DisplayObject() )` it throw an error saying " Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' "